# Laravel Redirect Intended cause unwanted url

Tags: php, laravel

when I use Redirect::intended on my localhost, it's working just fine and has no unwanted URL but when I use it on my dev server this happens. it should just be /invoice and no URL afterward, the %2Finvoice happens to be an encoded version of /invoice.

[image: unwanted url]

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using "GET" as your method? Using "POST" removes the display of additional info on your URL

Comment: GET, but i don't think that's matter. because it works fine and without unwanted url in localhost. that just happen in my dev server

Comment: What code generates that URL?

Comment: Redirect::intended

Comment: You should use `urldecode` (i.e. `urldecode(Redirect::intended)`) function.

Comment: Does the `%2` exist in the original link i.e. the link you click before you get redirected to the `login` page (or whichever page it is)? If so please can you show the code for that link.

Comment: @Rwd no, it doesn't. its: www.myweb.com/invoice

Comment: @Rwd like i said, in localhost it was fine and i use the exact same link except for the domain.

Comment: @Tpojka well i dont think i need to do it. cos it would make the url far messed. like the url was myweb.com/invoice?q=%2Finvoice, if i use decode it would became myweb.com/invoice?q=/invoice.